# Insert static rows in Target Table

Tags: sql, informatica

[image]

So I have a scenario based on the picture attached.

In my source table, I only have TIER 1 available value and will be inserted in the target table.

But the requirement requires that even if TIER 2 to 7 is not available, I should still insert it to the target table regardless if there is a value or not, and append a value of 0.

I tried making another flow and putting the condition in router but it seems to be tedious as the Department is dynamic and can be multiple depending on the source.

I would like to ask if there is another approach for this

Comment: It sounds like you want a trigger.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question. Iam clear on this

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm also thinking on applying trigger on this, but not sure yet since it would be my first time.

Comment: @user9192401 Hi, the question is about inserting static rows everytime the workflow runs. Based on the example, TIER 2 only has a value, but we should still insert other TIERS as this is needed for report generation

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it that I know of. First is to use a java transformation, where you can check how many rows are coming from source and generate the remaining using the generateRow() function within a for loop. The second option is to use a active lookup transformation, with a query like below. In the condition put rec_cnt>=src_cnt where src_cnt being the number records from source.

```
select rownum as rec_cnt
from dual
connect by rownum <= 7
```